# Extract multiple data from XML file using NSIS

Tags: xml, extract, nsis

How to extract multiple data from XML file using NSIS?
I used UpdateXml to download XML and extract only one value from it too many times.
Is it possible extract multiple values from XML file using UpdateXml or maybe I should use another command/plugin to get needed data?

Comment: Why not just use a loop?

Comment: because it downloads the same xml file too many times, it would be smart to download it once and get what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XML plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/XML_plug-in) to parse XML document and build DOM structure which you can use in your script. If the XML is not available locally, use [NSISSdl plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSISdl_plug-in) to download.